# JPanel drawing - why do I have to override paintComponent method?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, drawing

I am learning Java and I have started to play with drawing possibilities.

Basically I have 2 questions:

1. Why do I have to override `paintCompoment` method in order to paint something on `JPanel`?
2. Taking into account the first example when I call `f.add(new MyPanel());` it creates a new `MyPanel` object and draw the text. How come the text is drawn? Method `paintComponent(g)` is not called.

To me it looks like I have two options:

First one (from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html):

```
package painting;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class SwingPaintDemo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI(); 
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "+
        SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new MyPanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    public MyPanel() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(250,200);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);       

        // Draw Text
        g.drawString("This is my custom Panel!",10,20);
    }  
}
```

Second one: which works as well

```
Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0));
g.drawString("Hello", 200, 200);
g.draw3DRect(10, 20, 50, 15, true);
panel.paintComponents(g);
```

Comment: `canvas.getGraphics();` <- This is a bad idea

Comment: It's called by the painting subsystem: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html

Comment: Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details on how painting is done in Swing

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to call `paintComponent()` yourself.

The `paintComponent()` is called automatically (by the UI thread).

If you leave the `paintComponent()` method empty, it will be invoked but nothing will be painted because it is empty.

Comment: The swing library does not call paintComponent(). It is called but the UIThread, via awt's paint() method, which swing hands off to paintComponent

Comment: What did you try, exactly?

Comment: I tried this:
`Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0));
g.drawString("Hello", 200, 200);
g.draw3DRect(10, 20, 50, 15, true);
panel.paintComponents(g);`
and that worked, thus I didn’t understood, why do I have to extend JPanel and override paintComponent(Graphics g) in order to do the same as above.

Comment: You probably not call paintComponents directly. Try removing
panel.paintComponent(g); and see if it still works.

Comment: I am trying, but not it does not work at all. Never mind. If overridden paintCompoment method is the correct way, I will use that. Thanks a lot.